# Cross-sheet sum and speed performance

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to sum a lot of sheets (11-12) to a master called "Total - Resources" I have multiple ranges  I wan't to sum cell-for-cell however I can't seem to find a solution to add multiple ranges that needs to be added in the sht.Range? I am also experience massive speed problems when trying to add the different ranges like this... Is there a better, more straight forward way to do the same as described in the code.

- Use more ranges
- Speed performance

  ```
  For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
      If Sht.Name Like "*- Resources" Then
          For Each cell In Sht.Range("G11:G46")'Add another range "G22:G46","F46.."?
              Cast = cell.Address
              Sheets("Total - Resources").Range(Cast) = Sheets("Total - Resources").Range(Cast) + cell.Value
          Next cell
      End If
  Next Sht
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following:

1. Define your addresses `SumAddresses` that should sum up.
2. Handle these addresses area by area.
   *The address `A1:C4,A7:C10` consists of 2 areas: `A1:C4` and `A7:C10`*
3. Work with arrays. That means read the data in each area into an array. Then perform the sum calculation with the array, and in the end write that array into the destination area in your `Total` worksheet. Working with arrays in much faster than using ranges.

So you end up with something like:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SumResourceSheets()
    Dim SumAddresses As String
    SumAddresses = "A1:C4,A7:C10,D5" 'note this is limited to 255 characters!

    Dim ResultRange As Range
    Set ResultRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Total - Resources").Range(SumAddresses)
    ResultRange.ClearContents 'make result range epmty

    ReDim SumAreas(1 To ResultRange.Areas.Count) As Variant
    Dim iArea As Long
    For iArea = LBound(SumAreas) To UBound(SumAreas)
        SumAreas(iArea) = ResultRange.Areas(iArea).Cells.Value 'read area into array

        Dim ws As Worksheet
        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            If ws.Name Like "*- Resources" And ws.Name <> "Total - Resources" Then 'exclude Total - Resources
                If ws.Range(ResultRange.Areas(iArea).Address).Cells.CountLarge = 1 Then
                    'handle single cell areas…
                    SumAreas(iArea) = SumAreas(iArea) + ws.Range(ResultRange.Areas(iArea).Address).Value
                Else
                    'this is for multi cell areas …

                    'read data area into array
                    Dim DataArea() As Variant
                    DataArea = ws.Range(ResultRange.Areas(iArea).Address).Value

                    'sum data into sum array
                    Dim iRow As Long
                    For iRow = LBound(DataArea, 1) To UBound(DataArea, 1)
                        Dim iCol As Long
                        For iCol = LBound(DataArea, 2) To UBound(DataArea, 2)
                            If IsNumeric(DataArea(iRow, iCol)) Then
                                SumAreas(iArea)(iRow, iCol) = SumAreas(iArea)(iRow, iCol) + DataArea(iRow, iCol)
                            Else
                                MsgBox "The cell '" & ResultRange.Areas(iArea).Cells(iRow, iCol).Address & "' in worksheet '" & ws.Name & "' does not contain a number!", vbCritical
                                Exit Sub
                            End If
                        Next iCol
                    Next iRow
                End If
            End If
        Next ws

        ResultRange.Areas(iArea).Cells.Value = SumAreas(iArea) 'write area into cell
    Next iArea
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect..MUCH Faster :O However i got a type mismatch error on the second attempt:

                    Dim iCol As Long
                    For iCol = LBound(DataArea, 2) To UBound(DataArea, 2)
                        SumAreas(iArea)(iRow, iCol) = SumAreas(iArea)(iRow, iCol) + DataArea(iRow, iCol) 'Type Mismatch error

Comment: In which line? If it is in this line: `SumAreas(iArea)(iRow, iCol) = SumAreas(iArea)(iRow, iCol) + DataArea(iRow, iCol)` then probably there is a non-numeric value in the data area. Check your sheet's data. • Or is there a single cell in your list of addresses `SumAddresses`?

Comment: Does that mean only values is accepted. Not numberformatting e.g. percentages?

Comment: @Kaizan number formatted numbers are actually saved as numbers (not text), but if you have real text it cannot calculate with text (obviously). Also you did not answer my questions. Check my edited code which also can handle singe cell areas.

Comment: Or sorry.. there is a non-numeric value in the range :D

Comment: @Kaizan check my edit, it will check if it is numeric and if not it tells you which cell is causing the issue.

Comment: The ranges I have added is "F11:F46,F56:AS86,F96:AS126,F136:AS166,F176:AS206" Even after only having numeric-values I still get a type-mismatch. Is there to many/too long array.

Comment: Did you try my last edited code? It tells you which cell has a non-numeric value. If that doesn't help tell in which line you get the error.

Comment: I was way to slow for you.. It absolutely brilliant works :D YOU ARE FAST! Thanks :) Amazing help.

Comment: One last thing right now everything works perfect, however everytime a cell in the range is blank MSGBOX will appear. Is there a way to skip blanks?

Comment: @Kaizan of course, instead of `If IsNumeric(DataArea(iRow, iCol)) Then` use `If IsNumeric(DataArea(iRow, iCol)) Or DataArea(iRow, iCol) = vbNullString Then`